# SQL statement not giving me desired output when i do not have a certain column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve these values from mysql table using this statement in my node.js

```
          SELECT product.name, product.image, product.description, product.brand, product.price, review.rating       
            FROM product INNER JOIN review
            ON product.productid = review.productid
            WHERE product.name = ?
```

However, products that do not have a review assigned to them doesnt give me the desired output.

eg product 1 has a review assigned to it as shown in the review table and will give me my data, but product 2 does not have a review assigned to it and as a result, i do not get my data
[image]

Review Table

[image]

How do I fix this so as to achieve my desired output regardless of if the product has a review assigned to it.

Thank you

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: see docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing an inner join, which only returns rows where the productID matches in both tables. You need to do a left join so that if the productID does not exist in the review table, the matching row in the product table will still be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT product.name, product.image, product.description, product.brand, product.price, review.rating       
FROM product LEFT JOIN review
ON product.productid = review.productid
WHERE product.name = ?
```